# Django, get fully serialized object. All properties from many to many relationships

Tags: django, serialization, manytomanyfield

I'm looking for a way to serialize an entire object with all of it's relationships. I seem to be only able to get the primary key from the serializer now.

This is my model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Action Name', max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField('Message', blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField('Subject', max_length=40, null=True)
    recipient = models.ManyToManyField('Recipient', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return unicode(self.name).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.name)

class Recipient(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField('Address', max_length=75, unique=True)
    businessHours = models.BooleanField('Business Hours Only', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return unicode(self.address).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.address)
```

I run the serializer here:

```
all = serializers.serialize('xml', list(Action.objects.select_related().all()))
```

if I run print all I get output listing just the primary key for the recipient field.

```
<field type="CharField" name="subject">On The Road Productions</field>
<field to="sla.recipient" name="recipient" rel="ManyToManyRel">
<object pk="29"></object>
</field></object>
<object pk="11" model="sla.action">
<field type="CharField" name="name">On The Road Productions</field>
<field type="TextField" name="message">
```

I need all of the properties for the related Recipients also. Any idea how I can get this?

edit - I found this piece in

I found this piece in the xml_serializer.py but I'm not sure how to modify it.

```
def handle_m2m_field(self, obj, field):
    """
    Called to handle a ManyToManyField. Related objects are only
    serialized as references to the object's PK (i.e. the related *data*
    is not dumped, just the relation).
    """
    if field.creates_table:
        self._start_relational_field(field)
        for relobj in getattr(obj, field.name).iterator():
            self.xml.addQuickElement("object", attrs={"pk" :  smart_unicode(relobj._get_pk_val())})
        self.xml.endElement("field")
```

Comment: You could get a queryset of the related model and serialize them too?

Comment: Doesn't look like that maintains the relationships between the objects.

Answer (score 0):

would suggest to have a look at django-piston internals.

with django-piston it's no problem to do this and the code is pretty readable. so dive in.